# Reading coordinates from text file in python

Tags: python

I have a text file (`coordinates.txt`):

```
30.154852145,-85.264584254
15.2685169645,58.59854265854
...
```

I have a python script and there is a while loop inside it:

```
count = 0
while True:
 count += 1
 c1 = 
 c2 =
```

For every run of the above loop, I need to read each line (count) and set `c1,c2` to the numbers of each line (separated by the comma). Can someone please tell me the easiest way to do this?

============================

```
import csv

count = 0

while True:
        count += 1
        print 'val:',count
        for line in open('coords.txt'):
                c1, c2 = map(float, line.split(','))
                break
        print 'c1:',c1
        if count == 2: break
```

Comment: This is _exactly_ what the `csv` module is for.

Comment: i am really new to this..any help would be much appreciated

Answer (score 4):

The best way to do this would be, as I commented above:

```
import csv

with open('coordinates.txt') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for count, (c1, c2) in enumerate(reader):
        # Do what you want with the variables.
        # You'll probably want to cast them to floats.
```

I have also included a better way to use the `count` variable using `enumerate`, as pointed out by @abarnert.

Comment: +1. And if you need `count`, you can just use `enumerate(reader)`, instead of maintaining it manually.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for reminding me, I didn't think to include that. Updated.

Answer (score 0):

```
f=open('coordinates.txt','r')
count =0
for x in f:
    x=x.strip()
    c1,c2 = x.split(',')
    count +=1
```

Comment: This leaves in the newlines, which the OP won't want. Also, it bascically just reinvents `csv`.